# Can't make keyboard shortcut with super key and one other key on linux mint xfce

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I'm using linux mint 21.1 with Xfce 4.16.0. I'd like to map the `Show desktop` action in the window manager to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. I'd like to make have my `Show desktop` keyboard shortcut be mapped to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. When I try to set this keyboard shortcut in the Window Manager application, the shortcut doesn't work. It seems that shortcuts involving the Super key don't work unless there's an additional modifier like <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>involved.

I've read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/34280/1173734) stackexchange answer to a similar problem which says to change your super key to a different key combination. I'm ideally looking to be able to use the super key for my 2 stroke keyboard shortcuts though. Is this at all possible in linux mint?

Answer (score 0):

It is not Mint's problem. It is a recurring xfce's problem. This bug appears, fix published, bug appears again...

There is a workaround, which works in xfce, or at least worked last time I used xfce: https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey

Or you can replace xfce with Cinnamon or Mate. They have their own problems, but keyboard hotkeys were always working fine.